# Where can I find Java SDK 1.4.2 compatible with windows 32?

Tags: sdk, java, jdk1.4

I need Java SDK 1.4.2 on my system which is 32 bit compatible. I am unable to find it.
Can someone please help me out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you say why have to use such an old version?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I want this version for SP25 Netweaver Developer Studio 7.0 which requires this version or even older and I have already checked the links provided in some of the answers below but there is no SDK available there for 32 bit compatible system :(

Comment: When I follow the link and looked for the windows i586 version I can see it.  This is 32-bit for Windows. See my answer for the link.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to previous releases to get 1.4. Here is the [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop for windows version at the [Link to Java 1.4.2_18](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html#j2sdk-1.4.2_18-oth-JPR) others have provided.

I can see there is a j2sdk-1_4_2_18-windows-i586-p.exe which is the 32-bit version you need.